# Hazelcast dynamic wan replication configuration; possible?

Tags: hazelcast

I would like to be able to dynamically (at runtime) alter/define the WAN replication configuration. (i.e. not rely on a static config in XML)

Is this possible? If so any pointers to samples or what classes in the API I should be looking into?

Answer (score 3):

Hazelcast doesn't support on the fly configuration. please see https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/592

Comment: Does anyone know what the advantage is to WAN replication out of the box, vs just listing WAN connected Hazelcast IPs individually in the normal peer cluster setup?